# Transfer data from azure blob storage to hdfs file system

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have data in azure storage blob which is in parquet format. What I need to do is to transfer all those storage files to a hdfs. Is there any way I can do that?

couldn't find any helpful method to do it,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using @jay's solution I was able to transfer data using following command.

command:

```
hadoop  distcp -D fs.azure.account.key.<account name>.blob.core.windows.net=<Key> wasb://<container>@<account>.blob.core.windows.net<path to wasb file> hdfs://<hdfs path>
```

distcp copies directory structure recursively for more info read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-wasb-distcp)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statements in this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/index.html),actually,in Hadoop, an entire file system hierarchy is stored in a single container.

You could configure your account key and container name as below:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.key.youraccount.blob.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>YOUR ACCESS KEY</value>
</property>
```

[image]

So only you need to do just copy the files into the configured container with [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy).

More details,please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage#hdinsight-storage-architecture).

---

***Update Answer:***

I provide a solution here for you:

1.Install[BlobFuse](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse) on your VM to provide a virtual filesystem backed by your Azure Blob storage Container.

2.Then use [cp](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyFromLocal) command to copy files from `container directly` to HDFS URL.

### In addition,just write a snippet of java code to grab data from azure blob storage to dump into HDFS.

Just for summary, please use command:

```
hadoop  distcp -D fs.azure.account.key.<account name>.blob.core.windows.net=<Key> wasb://<container>@<account>.blob.core.windows.net<path to wasb file> hdfs://<hdfs path>
```

distcp copies directory structure recursively for more info read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-wasb-distcp)

Comment: We have VMs in azure upon which hdfs is setup it's not wasb:\\ it's hdfs:\\. Now we have parquet in azure blob storage which we want to copy to hdfs:\\.

Comment: @ShivinAgarwal Please refer to my update answer,hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried with the distcp command and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks.

Comment: @ShivinAgarwal Yeah,you could mark yourself or my updated answer to end this case,thanks a lot.