# Can AzCopy trasnfer files to Azure directly from HDFS instead of from local storage?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs, azure-blob-storage

I think I have a fairly straightforward question. I'm using a Hadoop cluster hosted on a Unix machine. And I need to transfer ORC files to an Azure BLOB storage from this Hadoop cluster.

If I install AzCopy on the Unix machine that hosts the Hadoop cluster, will I then be able to transfer the files to and fro HDFS and Azure?

All the information I see on the internet only talks about transfers between local storage to Azure. So, I'm still left confused about transfers from HDFS to Azure.

Can someone please help me in resolving this confusion about AzCopy? Would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use distcp for this. See solution from here (I just reversed the order of the params) https://stackoverflow.com/a/54514602/1537195

```
hadoop  distcp -D fs.azure.account.key.<account name>.blob.core.windows.net=<Key> hdfs://<hdfs path> wasb://<container>@<account>.blob.core.windows.net<path to wasb file>
```

Comment: But isn't `distcp` only for transfers into HDInsight cluster (WASB)? My Hadoop cluster is not hosted on Azure Data Lake. It's on a separate Unix box. Will `distcp` still work for me? This is one of the things that has always confused me.

Comment: no, the wasb driver should be included in more or less all normal hadoop clusters. See here: https://gerardnico.com/azure/wasb (Point: 7 - Code)

Comment: WASB has nothing to do with HDinsight, only with Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarification. So, the below command (in which I just changed the source and targets from your answer) `hadoop  distcp -D fs.azure.account.key.<account name>.blob.core.windows.net=<Key> hdfs://<hdfs path> wasb://<container>@<account>.blob.core.windows.net<path to wasb file> ` should transfer the files from my Hadoop cluster to Azure Blob, right?